# multiple labels & ImageView in CollectionView iOS

Tags: ios, collectionview

I'm planning to make a collectionview like this one row and 12 columns - [image: Storyboard Image]

In which, in the The two labels I want to print 2 string and in between them an image will print.

I've implemented two dataSource methods -

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return collection.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionview_cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.forecastHourlyTemp.text = "\(self.HourlyData[indexPath.row].temp)°C"
    cell.forecastHourlyTime.text = self.HourlyData[indexPath.row].dt.fromUnixTimeToTime()
    cell.forecastHourlyWeatherIcon.image = UIImage(named: self.HourlyData[indexPath.row].weather[0].icon)
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }
```

But instead of display these three it displays only images - [image: Output in Emulator]

In several places people use only images/ single label to demonstrate collectionview. So is it possible to display 3 view item at a time in collectionview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to size items of the collection inside the layout mechanism. So you may want to create a custom `FlowLayout` and make it divide the available with by 3:

```
class WeatherCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return assertionFailure("Collection view not found") }

        let availableWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
        let availableHeight = collectionView.bounds.height
        let itemWidth: CGFloat = (availableWidth/3).rounded(.down)
        itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: availableHeight)

        sectionInset = .zero
        minimumLineSpacing = .zero
        minimumInteritemSpacing = .zero 
    }
}
```

Then you should pass it as the layout of the `collectionView`.

In Storyboard:

[image: Demo]

or Code:

```
CollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: WeatherCollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

So no need for any fixed width.

---

#### Some notes

1. Don't forget the state where items are more than the desired count!
2. Don't forget to disable bouncing if you want it to just be fitted!
3. Don't forget to update the `availableWidth` (or `availableHeight`) if you want  to play with spacings
4. Don't repeat yourself! Exclude all repetitive data:

```
let forecast = self.HourlyData[indexPath.row]

cell.forecastHourlyTemp.text = "\(forecast.temp)°C"
cell.forecastHourlyTime.text = forecast.dt.fromUnixTimeToTime()
cell.forecastHourlyWeatherIcon.image = UIImage(named: forecast.weather[0].icon)
```

5. Use `lowerCamelcase` for everything you define in your code except for `type`s:

```
HourlyData -> hourlyData
```

6. Get rid of `self` where ever you can!
7. Get rid of `return` keyword where ever you can:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { collection.count }
```

8. Try **NOT** to use delegate methods for sizing collection items if you already know the size!

Answer (score 0):

After trying testing in various way I found out that the problem was in the height. When the size of the collectionView is greater than the cell height, Then it shrinks and made it two column. So At first I fixed the collectionView area equal to the cell height.

I found this solution with trying to print various number of items in the list like 1, 2, 3 then suddenly found this solution.

[image: Final Expected Output]